# When do we need to use [Browsable(true)]?

Tags: c#, .net

When do we need to use `[Browsable(true)]`?

**EDIT** (by SLaks): He's asking (I assume) why one would need to pass `true` as the parameter, given that it's already `true` by default.

Comment: Whenever you need the property to appear in the Properties window.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MSDN says [it all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx):

> Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a Properties window.

For example, if you're creating a User Control, you might want to decorate non-UI-related properties with `[Browsable(false)]` so that they will not be available through a "Properties" window.

Additionally, it controls which properties of an object can be seen in a [`PropertyGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx).

As for why we can pass `true` explicitly, I believe this is due to [`BrowsableAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes.aspx) property of a `PropertyGrid`. You can set it to contain [`BrowsableAttribute.No`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.no.aspx), so that the property grid will display all non-browsable members.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @SLaks: It answers the original question - just not your re-interpretation of it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my interpretation is correct.  (Otherwise, he would;t have said `true`)

Comment: how can I set the broswsable attribute programically?

Answer (score 27):

<strike>As far as I know, never.</strike>

## EDIT

I was wrong.
It's necessary if you want to make a property which has `[Browsable(false)]` in your base class   (such as  [`UserControl.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k5hkke.aspx)) browsable.

Comment: Good explanation of where it would specifically be used.

Answer (score 5):

Probably when you want to make damn sure no one changes it :P

```
// I want to see this, dont change it to false or I'll hunt you down...
[Browsable(true)]
public int MyProperty {
   get {
      // Insert code here.
      return 0;
   }
   set {
      // Insert code here.
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need the attribute; the comment alone should be good enough.

Comment: haha, that is true, but the browsable tells them exactly which attribute you are talking about

Comment: You could change the comment to `//Do NOT add [Browsable(false)]`

Comment: I just wonder why you would want to enforce the visibility of a property in the property pane to inheritors. So putting a comment to not inherit with `[Browsable(false)]` sounds a bit silly to me.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that things are browsable *by default*. The only scenario I can think where this would matter is overriding a member and *changing* the browsability... here `F` is visible only because of the `[Browsable(true)]` in the derived class - without it, it *isn't* visible.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.Run(new Form { Controls = {new PropertyGrid {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SelectedObject = new Bar()
        }}});
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string A { get; set; }
    public virtual string B { get; set; }
    public virtual string C { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)] public virtual string D { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)] public virtual string E { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)] public virtual string F { get; set; }
    [Browsable(true)] public virtual string G { get; set; }
    [Browsable(true)] public virtual string H { get; set; }
    [Browsable(true)] public virtual string I { get; set; }
}
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override string A { get { return base.A; } set { base.A = value; } }
    [Browsable(false)] public override string B { get { return base.B; } set { base.B = value; } }
    [Browsable(true)] public override string C { get { return base.C; } set { base.C = value; } }
    public override string D { get { return base.D; } set { base.D = value; } }
    [Browsable(false)] public override string E { get { return base.E; } set { base.E = value; } }
    [Browsable(true)] public override string F { get { return base.F; } set { base.F = value; } }
    public override string G { get { return base.G; } set { base.G = value; } }
    [Browsable(false)] public override string H { get { return base.H; } set { base.H = value; } }
    [Browsable(true)] public override string I { get { return base.I; } set { base.I = value; } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[BrowsableAttribute Class (System.ComponentModel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

The documentation states:

> A visual designer typically displays
>   in the Properties window those members
>   that either have no browsable
>   attribute or are marked with the
>   BrowsableAttribute constructor's
>   browsable parameter set to true.

`[Browsable]` also defaults to true.

...so technically, you never need `[Browsable(true)]` unless you want to be very explicit.

Comment: 'never .. except..' is not right/complete, mainly overriding base class that has a value `false`.

Answer (score 1):

One occassion when this attribute becomes important is during WebPart development for Sharepoint. In this scenario you are providing meta information for Sharepoint to determine whether your webpart should be viewable for selection etc. There are other similiar attributes such as Category and FriendlyName etc which are also taken into account.

See the following for examples:

[Creating a web part with custom properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28office.11%29.aspx)

And another with decent images of the sharepoint webpart editor which reflects your attributes:

[Making Sharepoint WebParts interact](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=WebParts2)

Answer (score 1):

The types and attributes in ComponentModel are not specifically tied to any particular designer. Although I don't know of any specific scenario that you would need to "opt in" to being designer-browsable, I suppose it's conceivable that you could have some component designer that would assume browsable(false).

I suppose you could also override a virtual property that specified browsable(false) and apply browsable(true) in the overridden member.

Comment: The Xamarin iOS designer defaults to properties being non-designable. You must specify [Browsable(true)] for them to appear in the property panel. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/#Custom_Properties

Answer (score 0):

A visual designer typically displays in the Properties window those members that either have no browsable attribute or are marked with the BrowsableAttribute constructor's browsable parameter set to true. These members can be modified at design time. Members marked with the BrowsableAttribute constructor's browsable parameter set to false are not appropriate for design-time editing and therefore are not displayed in a visual designer. The default is **true**.

so, the answer is you never *have* to, as it is done by default.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) you want it to be true when it should be displayed in the property window in VS. Basically it applies to classes that are used in the designer.

Comment: It's `true` by default.  You only need to specify the attribute when setting it to `false`.

Comment: yes, but properties are by default browsable. I think the OP asked if there are cases where a property needs this set to *true* in order to appear.

Comment: @SLaks and @Isak Save good points. I guess an attribute value of true makes sense when overriding a property in a parent class that has set it to false explicitly.