# Add a description for a property

Tags: c#

How do I add a text description for my property?

[image]

My code :

```
private bool _SpaceKey;

public bool SpaceKey
{
    get
    {
        return _SpaceKey;
    }
    set
    {
        _SpaceKey = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify your language, and include any needed picture directly in the question.

Answer (score 28):

Have a look at the [Description Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx):

```
[Description("This is the description for SpaceKey")]
public bool SpaceKey { get; set; }
```

You can additionally use the [Category Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.aspx) to specify the category of the property:

```
[Category("Misc")]
[Description("This is the description for SpaceKey")]
public bool SpaceKey { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want to see the description **in the Visual Studio designer** (or any other compatible IDE), you'll need to use [design-time attributes for components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8(v=VS.80).aspx) which are defined in [`System.ComponentModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.aspx) namespace.

```
[Description("This is the description of Space Key.")]
public bool SpaceKey { get; set; }
```

Before doing so, consider learning how to write a good description from descriptions in class library (though they're not always helpful, either). It's good to follow the existing style.

If you want to see hints **in code**, like tooltips when selecting a member with IntelliSense, you need to also use [XML comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) for documentation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets space key (that would probably make a bad summary).
/// </summary>
public bool SpaceKey { get; set; }
```

That's it.

Comment: the intellisense text description is being shown when using only the [Description] also

Comment: Whether or not Intellisense shows up may depend on your version of Visual Studio.  I'm using VS 2013, and [Description] does not display the help text in code, while the XML tags do.

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda Looks like its either-or, description or summary.

Answer (score 1):

(A bit late but maybe helpful to someone)

Another option that you can use is:

```
[Browsable(true)]
```

If the `Browsable` is `true`, you can see the property in Property Window and when its `false`, no one could not change it via Property Window in designer.
See [more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515726/when-do-we-need-to-use-browsabletrue) about that.

Answer (score 1):

In [Asp.net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.description?view=netframework-4.7.2) c# coding, it is different. Its work of all asp.net core version.

```
 [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]  
 public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
```